# R shiny, plot a hierarchical segmentation where user can input the cut level

Tags: r, shiny, hierarchical, dendrogram

In R Shiny I'm running and plotting (through a dendrogram) a hierarchical segmentation:

```
  hc <- reactive({
    if(length(kc()) == 0){
      return(NULL)
    }else{
      hc <- hclust(dist(kc()$centers), method="ward.D")
      return(hc)
    }
  })

  output$hc_plot <- renderPlot({
    if(is.null(hc())){
      return(NULL)
    }else{
      plot(hc(), main="dendrogram")
    }
  })
```

I'd like to let the user cut the dendrogram through an input field nb_kernel_hc so I'm doing:

```
  observe({
    if(input$nb_kernel_hc != input$nb_kernel){
      hc()$vecteur <- stats::cutree(hc(), k = input$nb_kernel_hc )
      rect.hclust(hc(), k=input$nb_kernel_hc, border="red")
    }
  })
```

But I'm getting:

> Warning: Error in stats::cutree: invalid 'tree' ('merge' component)

while it works perfectly in R

Comment: where is the code for `input$nb_kernel_hc` ? You should actually post reproducible example to make it easier for people to help You

Comment: I would look at `hc()` and `input$nb_kernel_hc` using `verbatimTextOutput` to see if they really contain what they should contain

Comment: BTW, you might find this interesting: https://github.com/yonicd/shinyHeatmaply